# Creating volume in custom Docker image on GCP causing error

Tags: angular, npm, google-cloud-platform, cypress, google-cloud-build

I have `Angular` app with `Cypress`. I wanted to create a simple pipeline configuration on `Google Cloud Build`.

```
images:
  - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/e2e-tests'

steps:
  # Install node_modules
  - name: node:10.16.3
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ['ci']
    id: install

  # Run linters
  - name: node:10.16.3
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ['run', 'lint']
    id: lint
    waitFor:
      - install

  # Run unit tests
  - name: node:10.16.3
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ['test']
    id: test
    waitFor:
      - lint

  # Run e2e tests
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/e2e-tests', '-f', 'docker/cypress/Dockerfile', '.' ]
    id: e2e
    waitFor:
      - lint

  # Build app for prod
  - name: node:10.16.3
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ['build']
    id: build
    waitFor:
      - test
      - e2e
```

Unfortunately I cannot use built-in `npm` image, because `Cypress` needs some additional libs installed. That's why I started building my own image.

```
# THIS ONE IS WORKING

FROM node:lts

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y \
    libgtk2.0-0 \
    libnotify-dev \
    libgconf-2-4 \
    libnss3 \
    libxss1 \
    libasound2 \
    xvfb

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV CI=1

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN npm ci
RUN npm run e2e:ci
```

It worked when I was copying the app into the container. But I have to install dependencies once again, so I decided to replace `COPY` with `VOLUME` to fast up the whole process.

```
# THIS ONE GETS AN ERROR LISTED BELOW

FROM node:lts

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y \
    libgtk2.0-0 \
    libnotify-dev \
    libgconf-2-4 \
    libnss3 \
    libxss1 \
    libasound2 \
    xvfb

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV CI=1

VOLUME . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm run e2e:ci
```

GCB log (newest first):

```
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:430: container init caused \"apply apparmor profile: apparmor failed to apply profile: open /proc/self/attr/exec: no such file or directory\"": unknown
---> Running in be2a7992ad86
Step 7/7 : RUN npm run e2e:ci
---> 4fc9a0a86172
Removing intermediate container 53ee0d15063f
---> Running in 53ee0d15063f
Step 6/7 : WORKDIR /app
---> dd7298b536a0
Removing intermediate container 7f15a02f79e2
---> Running in 7f15a02f79e2
Step 5/7 : VOLUME . /app
---> 63124861eb3d
Removing intermediate container 28231f3bbf16
---> Running in 28231f3bbf16
Step 4/7 : ENV CI=1
---> a2563c01781f
Removing intermediate container 1579023b86b1
---> Running in 1579023b86b1
Step 3/7 : ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
---> d765db9e3ddf
Removing intermediate container a0ac5fd5da98
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u4) ...
Setting up notification-daemon (3.20.0-1+b1) ...
Setting up libgtk-3-bin (3.22.11-1) ...
Setting up libgtk-3-0:amd64 (3.22.11-1) ...
Setting up librest-0.7-0:amd64 (0.8.0-2) ...
...
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show how you call your custom builder ?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere What do you mean? It is run from `# Run e2e tests` in the first code block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the command RUN, you launch a command during the BUILD of the container. Like the `apt-get` that you perform: you run the installation of the packages.

When you build your custom Cloud Builder, you can't set a volume at the container build time. Thereby, you don't have to RUN the command.

Replace the `RUN` at the end by `ENTRYPOINT` which defines the default command to run when the container is executed.

Then, when you use your container, don't forget to specify the volume